# Reloading currently displayed UIView controller on button push

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a ViewController displayed modally and I wanted to have a refresh button on the same view controller and on pushing it, wanted to reload the same controller as if it was loaded for the first time. Is this the way to do this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //dismiss the current view controller
// shown modally
ViewController *viewController = [[viewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:nil];
[viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

This is the code that I have to load this controller from another view controller when the user clicks a button.

Please help.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that. Is there data inside the view controller that needs to be updated?

Comment: No backend data except that I have a countdown timer (runs from 30 secs) that I want to start again, show a label with some text (shown randomly) and some static buttons. This is a puzzle like app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't need to reload the whole controller. Just use the target/action pattern on the refresh button to call a setup method that resets your timer and randomly selected text.

Specifically:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.refreshButton addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  [self refreshData];
}

- (void)refreshData {
  // setup timer
  // setup randomly selected text
}
```

Comment: what about animation? I would like to redisplay the view controller with animation. How is it possible?. Also, does the above code considered bad and prone to memory leaks or unncessary CPU cycles?

Comment: the viewDidLoad method is only called once when the controller is loaded. and the refreshData would only be called upon the initial load and when you hit the refresh button. no memory/processing concerns.

Comment: regarding animations, instantiating an entirely new viewController from itself is not a good practice to accomplish an animation. take a quick look at [this Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html) for an overview of animation options. i cannot recommend anything more specific w/o knowing what type of animation you are trying to accomplish. granted, that should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I was actually referring to the code I posted before. Do you think the code I posted is prone to leaks and/or CPU cycles?.  I changed it a bit:[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
ViewController *viewController = [[viewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:nil];
[viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //dismiss the current view controller
// shown modally

Comment: Gotcha. That code is good w/ exception of having the view controller dismiss itself. Apple recommends using a delegate to dismiss the (presented) modal view controller - [see this reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW3). Note that a completely different alternative is to venture into storyboards, which help handle these transitions for you.

Comment: I'm not using storyboards as I wanted to support beginning with iOS 4.3+. I read the Apple reference material and the only thing I'm missing is a delegate line.